# Place 7 components in Jpanel, the first 6 in 3 rows and 2 columns. the last in a 3rd row but in between columns

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, gridbaglayout

Is it possible to do this using Grid Bag layout/ constraints without adding extra space to right or left of first 2 rows?

Should look like this roughly:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hy4I5.png]

Is there a better layout approach? doesnt have to be grid bag layout

Comment: This is easily handled by the `GridBagLayout`. The component in the 4th row needs to span 2 columns and then be centered within those two columns. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) for more information. You will need to use the `gridwidth` and `anchor` constraints.

Comment: :) so simple, yet took me forever, thanks so much!